# Como separar respostas de texto no R?

Tags: r

Tenho certeza que a minha dúvida deve ser super simples de ser solucionada para até agora não tive nenhum resultado positivo em nenhum dos tutoriais que acessei.

Estou trabalhando em um df no R que existe uma coluna que as respostas foram separadas por ; ou seja, cada participante poderia responder mais uma opção (Exemplo:Mapeamento do conhecimento, Feedback automático,Inteligência artificial,Colaboração e coautoria). Preciso separar as respostas de forma que consiga identificar quantos usuários responderam cada uma das opções sem alterar o número de participantes/respondentes.

Muito obrigada, 
Priscila.

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Eu faria qualquer coisa como `resp <- lapply(df, strsplit, ","); table(unlist(resp))`. Mas sem ver os dados é impossível ter a certeza. Edite **a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(head(df, 20))`, por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função `multi.split` do pacote `questionr`. Para visualizar o resultado, use `multi.table`.

```
v <- c("red,blue","green","red,green","blue,red")
multi.split(v, split.char = ",")
## Tabela de frequências
multi.table(multi.split(v, split.char = ","))

        n %multi
v.blue  2     50
v.red   3     75
v.green 2     50
```